# Can I use KVM without ioctl?

Tags: linux, kvm, stdio

Recently I've discovered how `/dev/kvm` doesn't seem to implement functionality for `read()` or `write()`, and any attempt to invoke them always results in Error 22 (Invalid argument).

I'm trying to avoid using ioctl calls, and am wondering if it's possible to use kvm at all if I were to completely remove ioctl support from the kernel.

How would I invoke access to kvm without ioctl?

Comment: And what exactly would you like to achieve by reading/writing to that device? Details of the API can be found at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/virt/kvm/api.html

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas something like: `write( kvm, "\x00\x00\xae\x00" );` (KVM_GET_API_VERSION) followed up by an async `version = read( kvm, 4 );`, similar to how you'd use `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` or any other file interface really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform read(2)/write(2) to /dev/kvm because it doesn't support these operations. If you take a look at the kvm driver source for your kernel or [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/virt/kvm/kvm_main.c) for example, you'll see that it only supports IOCTLs.

Since `read` and `write` operations are set to NULL in fops, read(2)/write(2) will fail with `-EINVAL` (Invalid argument) (ref: LDD3, chapter 3, file operations).

I've listed the relevant parts of the source virt/kvm/kvm_main.c below.

Here, the file_operations and the miscdevice:

```
static struct file_operations kvm_chardev_ops = {
    .unlocked_ioctl = kvm_dev_ioctl,
    .llseek     = noop_llseek,
    KVM_COMPAT(kvm_dev_ioctl),
};

static struct miscdevice kvm_dev = {
    KVM_MINOR,
    "kvm",
    &kvm_chardev_ops,
};
```

Driver init registers the miscdevice, exposing /dev/kvm to userspace:

```
int kvm_init(unsigned vcpu_size, unsigned vcpu_align, struct module *module)
{
    :
    /*
     * Registration _must_ be the very last thing done, as this exposes
     * /dev/kvm to userspace, i.e. all infrastructure must be setup!
     */
    r = misc_register(&kvm_dev);
    if (r) {
        pr_err("kvm: misc device register failed\n");
        goto err_register;
    }

    return 0;
    :
}
```

Comment: that's a shame, thank you for explaining